# Folium - Choropleth doesn't seem to be working

Tags: pandas, geojson, geopandas, folium

I'm new to geopandas and folium but I'm struggling with this particular issue. I want to put my wards on my choropleth, and I was able to do it, but everything is solid as opposed to what I want it to be, the higher the number the lighter it is and the lower the number the darker it is. Any help would be great, here is my code:

```
state_geo = os.path.join('OSNI_Open_Data_Largescale_Boundaries_Wards_2012.geojson')

m.choropleth(
    geo_data=state_geo,
    name='choropleth',
    data=merged,
    columns=['WARDNAME','D1_Income_rank'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='Greys',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)'
)


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save('#292_folium_chloropleth_USA1.html')
```

My values for ward name and D1_Income_rank can be found in the table 'merged':
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttnno.png)

Here is the html output which shows my issue as well:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WGbn.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've looked up our geojson dataset, it seems you got the wrong `key_on` value. From the start of the geojson:

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"FID":1,"OBJECTID":1,"WARDNAME":"ABBEY", ...`

So in this case the right `key_on` value would be `feature.properties.WARDNAME`.

There is an issue open in folium to fix this by validating the `key_on` argument, so if you want you're welcome to come help out!
https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/918

Comment: how does one in general finds what's the correct `key_on`?